# Display a different version of the background image on mobile devices

Tags: css, image, mobile, responsive-design, background

currently i can see the full screen image on desktops/laptop browsers, however i am trying to work out how to show a different image (because for now its just an image and there is no layout as its a holding page) on mobile devices mainly iphones or androids. I checked all threads here but could not find a proper solution to my issue. Would be great if someone could help me please to understand and learn how this would work for my future projects.

bg.jpg is for desktops

bgm.jpg is for mobile devices

Here is the HTML code i have currently. Its basically a 5 min quick thing to just get the holding page up with inline css and it looks fine on the desktop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>X</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        
        html { 
            background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .bgm {
    background: url(images/bgm.jpg);
  }
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bgm"></div>
    
 <style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No one has needed the vendor prefixes for background-size in many, many years. You can remove those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it right except your media query. It should be :

```css
.bgm {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .bgm {
    background: url(images/bgm.jpg);
    height: 50rem;
  }

  html {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

Notice the `max-width`instead. I also set background to none on the html element. Also since there's nothing inside your div with the class `bgm`, I gave it a min-height of `100vh` just so that I can see it.

To learn more about CSS media query : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thanks mate! but it didnt work on mobile. Now it just zooms in for some reason. Thats the website i am referring to: http://karaspa.co/ I am checking this on an iPhone 12 Pro, so if i remove the media query and revert back then it shows 'some of the image' If i inspect the image on responsive layout then for some odd reason it take bg.jpg and not bgm.jpg - Maybe there is a simple solution to this frustrating issue or i am doing something wrong here.